# The autonomous diameter of the group of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms of the standard symplectic space

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry

The autonomous norm of a Hamiltonian diffeomorphism $h$ of a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ is the smallest number $n\in \mathbf N$ such that $h=a_1\dots a_n$, where $a_i$ are autonomous diffeomorphisms. It is a norm on the group $\operatorname{Ham}(M,\omega)$.

Michael Brandenbursky and I recently observed that the diameter of the autonomous norm of $\operatorname{Ham}^c(\mathbf R^{2n})$ is either 2 or 3 ([see here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02864)).

**Question:** Is it 2 or 3?